# Use pg_dump result as input for pg_restore

Tags: postgresql

I need to clone a database (only schema) on the same server.
I would like to use the input from pg_dump and pipe it to pg_restore. I know this can be done with psql but psql doesn't have a "-c clean" option.

Is this possible but with pg_restore ?

```
 pg_dump --schema public dbName | psql dbNameTest
```

Comment: Did you try `pg_dump --format=c ... | pg_restore ...`

Comment: Use `pg_dump --schema-only (-c -C ... more options ...) databasename >myfile.sql`, and edit the outputfile before submitting it with psql. The output of --schema-only is not that big.

Comment: What's wrong with using psql?

Comment: pg_restore comes with `--jobs` option that lets you use all of the cpus to restore the backup, which makes restore faster.

Answer (score 29):

The following comes close:

```
pg_dump --schema-only --format c dbName | \
  pg_restore --schema-only --clean --dbname=dbNameTest
```

Except it doesn't work if the `dbNameTest` doesn't exist yet. The following does the job (although it complains if the `dbNameTest` already exists. I can live with that)

```
createdb dbNameTest
pg_dump --schema-only --format c dbName | \
  pg_restore --schema-only --clean --dbname=dbNameTest
```

A oneliner with short options would be:

```
createdb dbNameTest ; pg_dump -s -F c dbName | pg_restore -s -c -d dbNameTest
```

A sh script `pg_copy_schema` would go something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$2" ] ; then echo "Usage: `basename $0` original-db new-db" ; exit 1 ; fi
echo "Copying schema of $1 to $2"
createdb "$2" 2> /dev/null
pg_dump --schema-only --format c "$1" | pg_restore --schema-only --clean --dbname="$2"
```

Comment: Nice job with this answer, looks pretty clean, useful code. Why `--schema-only` though?

Comment: The op wanted to only copy the DB schema

Comment: Note that pg_restore cannot be piped to the output of pg_dump. If so, something like "parallel restore from stdin not supported". At least with v12.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html

You need to use -F combined with -c , -d, or -t option with pg_dump in order to use it with pg_restore. You can't use pg_restore with a plain-text SQL dump.