# Postgres backup not copying contents

Tags: database, postgresql

I am working on PostgreSQL database and we have a test server which needs to have the same data set as the production one. For this, I plan to start a daily CRON job in linux and copy the production database along with its contents like tables, rows, columns, sequences.

I checked how to copy databases from one to another, and I used the `pg_dump` command as I will write it below, but it only copied the database tables, sequences, but not the contents.

What should I do to copy the contents?

```
pg_dump -C databaseName | ssh -C username@removeHost.com "psql databaseName"
```

*Edit*

- So, What I did was I deleted the database which was on test server,
  created a new empty database and then used the command above, and it
  worked. So I guess I need to delete the database then only it will
  overwrite it.
- What should I do to circumvent this behaviour and do a force update
  of the database, or delete the test server database even if it is use
  and create a new empty database.

Comment: Why is stackoverflow not formatting the post even when I select the text and hit ctrl+k. Tried it twice already?

Comment: Because you were "inside" a "list" - in that case you need 8 spaces and not just 4

Comment: This is because if you have code directly after a list you'll have to either put the code under the list (and you have to indent 8 instead of 4 spaces for that), or alternatively put a comment to distinctuate it from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `pg_restore` instead of `psql` ? `pg_restore` has special arguments for your case: `-c` `-C`.

Details here:http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

An example of a command to dump/transfer/restore a db:

```
pg_dump -F c databaseName | ssh -C username@removeHost.com 'pg_restore --clean --create -d postgres'
```

For this command you need an empty db on target instance to connect to. (`postgres` in example).

> database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE
>   and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is restored into the database
>   name that appears in the archive.

If you already have a db on target instance:

```
pg_dump -F c databaseName | ssh -C username@removeHost.com 'pg_restore --clean -d databaseName'
```

Similar question: [Use pg_dump result as input for pg_restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103279/use-pg-dump-result-as-input-for-pg-restore)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can use it in my situation. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. I tried dropping the database manually, but because tomcats webapp is connected, I get an error that there are sessions connected, is there any way to force the database drop?

Comment: @WeareBorg You can drop active connections to DB. See this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected

Comment: @WeareBorg Or you can use second command in the example. It will overwrite the DB without dropping it but you may have problems with DB locks from your application.

Comment: Cool. I will use the 2nd command. Right now, I was running a cron task at 2:30am to restart the db and drop the db(then only it gets dropped) and sending data at 3:00am. What you have looks more elegant.