# pgAdmin - Create Script for db including all schemas and tables?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there a way to a `CREATE Script recursive` in pgAdmin where you could right-click on the db and it would give you the CREATE Scripts for the db and all of its schemas and tables in one shot?

I know I can right-click on a db, schema or table and generate a create script for that one particular thing, but in a db with dozens of tables it becomes a tedious cut and paste chore if you want to save all the necessary scripts.

Comment: I don't know enough about pgAdmin to give you an answer. You could try pg_dump to extract create scripts for a database schema. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103279/use-pg-dump-result-as-input-for-pg-restore

Comment: Right. Forget about pgAdmin for tasks like that.