# Use cmd to transfer data from a table from stage to prod environment?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pg-dump

I am using pg_dump and psql command separately. First, I use pg_dump to download all the data from my dev/stage environment.

```
pg_dump -U homedbuser -h pg.stage.ylopo -p 5445 -t bi.mktg_perf_party_campaign_mtd  homelistings > C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\campaign.sql
```

After which a sql file is created. There is a owner privilege attached to it, which isn't present in prod environment, so I have to edit this sql query.

After editing the query, I have to switch to prod server. And carry out the following psql command on prod environment.

```
psql -U homedbuser -h pg.prod.ylopo -p 5443 -t bi.mktg_perf_party_campaign_mtd_bkp -d homelistings  -1 -f C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\campaign.sql
```

Is there a way I could do this all in one step, in cmd, or another platform,in a split second, without changing from dev to prod environment?

Comment: What is an "owner privilege"?  What specific edit do you make to the file?  What is involved in switching "environments" or "servers"?

Comment: -t options for psql doesn't do what you think.  You should only specify that for pg_dump or for pg_restore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
-O
--no-owner
```

> Do not output commands to set ownership of objects to match the original database. By default, pg_dump issues ALTER OWNER or SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION statements to set ownership of created database objects. These statements will fail when the script is run unless it is started by a superuser (or the same user that owns all of the objects in the script). To make a script that can be restored by any user, but will give that user ownership of all the objects, specify -O.
> [manual 8(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

So at least you don't need to edit the file

But as one liner you could try [Use pg_dump result as input for pg_restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103279/use-pg-dump-result-as-input-for-pg-restore)  but in the comments wass metioned that it doesn't work anymore, but  you can test it, to be sure

Comment: pg_restore only works for certain formats (-F...)of pg_dump.  For "plain text" format, you need psql.

Comment: yes i now, but i don't know  a way to pipe the result in to pspl, but if you know feel free to answer

Comment: In general you just string them together, same as any other pipe.  `pg_dump ... | psql ...`.  But without knowing what switching environments and switching servers means, I can't be more specific.

Comment: piping doesn't work afaik,, and he wants to extract the database and send it o the same server i think